# Gitlab deployment via ssh which user rights

Tags: linux, apache, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I want to update my application with gitlab. For this i need user with private key stored in gitlab ci vars. My question is which user, with desired rights can I use to do deployments with gitlab-ci to server. Can i use the `www-data` user that has rights only for www dir or other user with root priviliges?

Currently I use `www-data` user for deployment. I am afraid that is insecure.

Comment: I don't understand, are you trying to `push` to `gitlab` with `ssh key` and can't find your key ?

Comment: No i want to deploy my git repo on server with gitlab-ci via ssh.  And my question which user do i have to create so that this is safe?